# Fine Uploader - set netUploads on initialise

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I've current set my itemLimit to 5 which works great but I need to set the 'netUploads' when I initialise 'fineuploader()'. The reason is when a user comes back (edit) to the post they might already have uploaded 3 images meaning they can only upload 2 more images but at the moment 'netUploads' is set to '0' and they can upload another 5 images making it 8. 'netUploads' should be set to 3 only allowing them to upload 2.

I know I can do this `$(this).fineUploader("getNetUploads");` which will get me the number but I can't see a 'set'. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the `itemLimit` accordingly on initialization.  If the user is only allowed to upload 3 more files, the `itemLimit` should be 3.  `getNetUploads` returns the number of net files uploaded during the current session.

### Update

A [feature request in the Github repo](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/999) has been opened to track this.  In the meantime, perhaps the following workaround will be useful:

```js
$("#uploader").fineUploader()
    .on("validate", function() {
        if (itemLimitOverride > 0) {
            return itemLimitOverride > $(this).fineUploader("getNetUploads");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Good idea. But what happens if I set 'itemLimit' to 3 and then the user decides to delete an image that was uploaded before. This means they will be able to upload 4 now. I can't change 'itemLimit' as its already been initialised. Any ideas? I should also say the delete function is completely separate from fine uploader as I'm using RubyOnRails to do this.

Comment: Are you simply looking to change the `itemLimit` for an already initialized Fine Uploader instance, based on new information that has been received client-side after Fine Uploader has been constructed?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I need to dynamically change the `itemLimit` after Fine Uploader has been constructed, which could change at anytime depending if an old image has been deleted.

Comment: There is not a straightforward way to do that at this time, but I can see how that might be useful.  Can you open up a feature request in the issue tracker so we can discuss and schedule this?  Also, I may be able to provide you with a workaround.

Comment: Great. I will open a feature request for you. Please let me know if there is a workaround for the time being?

Comment: We can discuss a workaround in the feature request.  I'll update my answer with this workaround as well.

Comment: Thanks.  We're releasing 3.9 today, so we'll comment on the feature request once that is behind us.

Comment: so what is `itemLimitOverride`? why not simply use `itemLimit` again here? I mean, the user is allowed 5. he dragged 4 (they were uploaded), now he drags 2 more. `getNetUploads` will return `4` on the second dragN'drop I assume. anyway, there should be some method "onBeforeUpload" to show some kind of warning or cancel the upload if there are more files than the limit allowed.

Comment: We'll be implementing this as part of Fine Uploader 5.1.0.